# Launch GWT CodeServer that should be able to pick-up sources from several maven multi-module projects

Tags: java, maven, gwt, plugins

I need to launch GWT CodeServer that should be able to pick-up sources for recompiling from several maven multi-module projects.
For one multi-module project I can use **gwt:run-codeserver** goal of **gwt-maven-plugin**.
But for several multi-module projects I need to build classpath of sources from all my projects.
Who can advise something?
May be developing my own MOJO can help me?
It's not about any IDE. I need to launch it 'manually'.